# How can I insert multiple values into a list? (python)

Tags: python, string, list, join

In Python, I want to add a space to each string in the list. The result is irrelevant whether it is a string or a list. But I would like to get the number of all cases where there can be spaces in the string.

first, I tried like this, Make string to list.

```
sent = 'apple is good for health'
sent.split(' ')
sentence = []
b = ''

for i in sent:
    c = ''
    for j in sent[(sent.index(i)):]:
        c += j
    sentence.append((b+' '+c).strip())
    b += i

sentence
```

In this case, the result obtain a string that contains **only one space**.

I also tried

```py
for i in range(len(sent)):
     sent[i:i] = [' ']
```

and another try is used `' '.join(sent[i:])`
but the results are same.

how can I get 
`'apple isgoodforhealth', 'appleis goodforhealth', 'appleisgood forhealth', 'appleisgoodfor health', 'appleis goodfor health', 'apple isgood forhealth', 'appleisgood forhealth' ...`
like this?

I really want to **get the number of all cases**.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your expected output is. For input of 'apple is good for health', you want the output to print the number 4?

Comment: Sorry I'm not good at English. for the explain again, I want to get the number of all cases where there can be space in the string. if the sentence is 'ABCDE', then result is 'A BCDE', 'AB CDE', 'ABC DE', 'ABCD E', 'AB CD E', 'A BC DE', 'ABC DE', 'A BCD E', 'ABCD E'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on the problem utilizing [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```
import itertools

sent = 'apple is good for health'
sent = sent.split(' ')

# Get indices for spaces
N = range(len(sent) - 1)

for i in N:
    # Get all combinations where the space suits
    # Note that this doesn't include the option of no spaces at all
    for comb in itertools.combinations(N, i + 1):
        # Add space to the end of each word
        # with index contained in the combination 
        listsent = [s + " " if j in comb else s for j, s in enumerate(sent)]
        # Make the result a string or count the combinations if you like
        tempsent = "".join(listsent)
        print(tempsent)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Join:-**

```
sent = 'apple is good for health'                 
sent = sent.split(' ')             
start_index = 0
last_index = len(sent)
for i in range(len(sent)-1):       
    first_word = "".join(sent[start_index:i+1])   
    second_word = "".join(sent[i+1:last_index])
    print(first_word, " ", second_word)
```

> Hope the above code will give output your way i.e, 'apple
>   isgoodforhealth', 'appleis goodforhealth', 'appleisgood forhealth etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help :-)